# How to reduce the size of the activeadmin form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am building a rails apps using activeadmin. How to reduce the size of the Activeadmin form when creating the form elements. It fully grabs the size of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The default css for active_admin is in the active_admin gem. If you'll inspect the style in your Chrome, you will see the style comes from somewhere like:

```
/gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_forms.scss
```

You can change them gem - but it is not recommended as it will be an overkill,

To set up a custom field to **ALL** fields in your active admin you will need to add your style in `active_admin.css.scss`:

```
.my_class {
    width: 200px;
}
```

and then to apply in to your active_admin fields. like that:

```
f.input :my_field, :input_html => { :class => 'my_class'}
```

Answer (score 0):

For styling the html tags you can use css or boot strap. You can learn the basics of css from MDN. In boot strap the entire screen is divided into grids so it works for different screen sizes as well.